# Header title is empty in TabNavigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Header title seems to not work as expected.

I already updated react-native and all other dependencies to their latest version and reviewed react-navigation documentation. Also I created a bug on github for this item.

Can you please take a look if I doing something wrong? I need to have header title set when i am using TabNavigation

```
const RootNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    ...publicScreens,
    Private: {
        screen: PrivateNavigator
    }
}, publicScreensConfig);

const privateScreens = {
    ContactList: {
        screen: ContactList
    },
    Settings: {
        screen: Settings
    }
};
```

.....

```
export default createBottomTabNavigator( privateScreens, options );
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import GlobalColors from '../../config/colors';

export default class Settings extends Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        title: 'Settings',
        headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: GlobalColors.grayDark,
        },
        headerTintColor: 'white',
        headerTitleStyle: {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        },
        gesturesEnabled: false,
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
        <Text> Settigs </Text>
      </View>
        )
    }
}
```

But I see empty header title in the header pane.
I want to see header text that come from navigation Options

[image: Empty header]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [JinHoSo](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5414#issuecomment-449940412) answer is here

```
const bottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator(...)

bottomTabNavigator.navigationOptions = ({navigation, screenProps}) => {
  const childOptions = getActiveChildNavigationOptions(navigation, screenProps)
  return {
    title      : childOptions.title,
    headerLeft : childOptions.headerLeft,
    headerRight: childOptions.headerRight,
  }
}
```

Comment: I am new to react-native and having similar issue. Where should I keep getActiveChildNavigationOptions? I have BottomTabNavigator inside StackNavigator

Comment: @AarthTandel import getActiveChildNavigationOptions from 'react-navigation' and put it right after you create bottomTabNavigator

Comment: Function `getActiveChildNavigationOptions ` has been removed from React Navigation. To set title properly follow this quick guide: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state